# How to build neural network in this structure？with different nodes connects to different number of nodes in next layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I only know how to use the built-in network like RNN of LSTM in PyTorch. But they tend to deal with every node in the previous layer that will give information to all nodes in the next layer.

I want to do something different but don't know how to code it myself. Like in this figure: the node *a* maps to all [*d*, *e*, *f*]  three nodes in layer 2, while node *b* maps to [*e*,*f*] and node *c* only maps to [*f*]. As a result,  node *d* will only contain information from *a*,  while *e* will contain information from  [*a*, *b*]. And *f* will contain information from all nodes in the previous layer.
Does anyone know how to code this structure? PLS give me some insight I'll be very grateful :D

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imp4f.png)

Answer (score 1):

When you have a layer that looks like Fully-Connected layer but with custom connectivity, use a **mask** with proper structure.

Let's say `x = [a, b, c]` is your 3-dim input and `W` denotes the connectivity matrix.

```
>> x
tensor([[0.1825],
        [0.9598],
        [0.2871]])
>> W
tensor([[0.7459, 0.4669, 0.9687],
        [0.9016, 0.4690, 0.0471],
        [0.5926, 0.9700, 0.5222]])
```

then `W[i][j]` points to the connecting weight between `j`th input and `i`th output neuron. To build the structure similar to your toy example, we would make a mask like this

```
>> mask
tensor([[1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Then you can simply mask the `W`

```
>> (mask * W) @ x
tensor([[0.1361],
        [0.6147],
        [1.1892]])
```

Note: `@` is matrix multiplication and `*` is pointwise multiplication.

Comment: So if my input dim is 3, output dim is 3. My neural network structure will be like {input 3 dim, LSTM_layer(3, 64),  Fully-connected_layer(64, 3), * lower triangular mask matrix(3, 3), output dim 3}. Will that work out as my custom  connectivity, to make the last three nodes getting differerent information? Or should I put the mask matrix between input layer(3,1) and LSTM layer(3,64)

Comment: Is your input sequential (you have LSTM in between) ? Your figure shows only Fully-connected layers. The solution I provided is only for masking the FC layer.

Comment: Sorry I made the figure simple. My input is time series values(values, hour_index, week_index) and I want to use an LSTM layer to extract some information between input(3 dim) and output(3 dim). So if I use a mask after LSTM layer, will the output three nodes be like: the d node only contains week information, e node contains week and hour, f node contains values, hour, week information?